# How can i revoke the access granted to web application to my organization's azure AD?

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

I have Office 365 Developer account & tenant in windows azure to manage office 365 users.
using consent framework "prompt=admin_consent", i granted access rights to one of my web application already registered in Azure AD (which is managed by me) to use office 365 API services, After granting access using admin consent, all my Azure AD users are able to authenticate themselves against Azure AD.
I am able to see the applications that i granted access using http://myapps.microsoft.com
but i am not able to revoke access granted for applications using this URL.
How can i revoke the access granted to my or third party application from my organization's azure AD?

Answer (score 5):

Let me check with our Azure folks, but I believe if you granted admin consent you can remove it from the Azure Management Portal. When you navigate to apps, you will see apps that you've consented to along with apps that you've developed. You can remove it there.

Comment: Yes its available within Azure managment portal but can't we revoke application access from office 365 portal (https://portal.office.com/)?
Is it mandatory for Office 365 subscription user to have access in Azure management portal to revoke application access ?

Comment: For end users that want to revoke access to applications that they consented to for themselves only, then myapps.microsoft.com is the place to do it. For administrators that gave admin consent, you revoke via the Azure portal. The Office 365 Portal doesn't have this ability from what I can see.

Comment: Am I over looking something? The applications listed on http://myapps.microsoft.com don't have a Revoke option... only "Get info" and "Report a Problem".

Comment: There should be a "Remove" option in there. If an app doesn't have that option, then it means your org admin consented to the app on your behalf, and you can't remove it.

Comment: https:/myapps.microsoft.com gets now auto redirected to https://myapplications.microsoft.com, however, I see only the standard MS apps there (like Teams, OneNote or Power Automate), but none of the custom apps developed by us. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

After logging into your Microsoft user account, navigate to https://account.live.com/consent/Manage. This will display all the apps you've authorised to access resources on your behalf. Here select the application you want to revoke access for.

[image]

This will show you [which permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#scopes-and-permissions) you've previously granted to the selected app and when you used them last. As you can see in the screenshot below I had granted `openid`, `Calendars.Read` and `Mail.Send`.

Once here all you have to do is click the button at the bottom labelled ***"Remove these permissions"*** and that should be it.

[image]

Comment: Even after removing these permissions. I am able to fetch events via api. Shouldn't it block the api from that client fully?

Comment: @Sk.Irfan that's very strange. That never happened to me before. Are you entirely sure about this? Check that you don't have more than one organisation associated with that same user. I had more than one and it got very confusing at some point.

Comment: Yes @Mig82. Till the access token is active, it is working. Ideally it should invalidate the access token as well right at the time we revoke because it is a big security concern if the access is in the hands of a wrong org as the data can still be retrieved for one hour of access token expiry.

Comment: I agree, but in my case revoking the permissions always took effect immediately. I advise you should open a support ticket with Microsoft. Don't know what else to tell you. I wish I could be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

if you have an admin rights go straight to: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/AllApps/menuId/
and remove it there

Answer (score 0):

If you have an organisation account with Microsoft you should be able to access this page: https://portal.office.com/account

From there click either `App permissions` on the left, or `Change app permission` in the middle.
[image: Office Account Portal]

This will take you to a screen that looks like this:
[image: app permissions]

Where you can revoke which app permissions you don't want anymore.

Comment: it states "You can't revoke permission because this has been assigned to you as part of a subscription or an admin role."
I'm an admin, but maybe I need to do it by another window somewhere else?

Comment: @KubaMiszcz that's very strange. There are permissions which you would not be able to remove because they could be granted by the admin as part (for example) app registrations. These will appear in the section below though. If you see the revoke button, it should be fine. Check if there is perhaps an active admin consent granted on an app registration within the organization on azure (if you are using azure, if not, I'm really sorry, I have no idea )

Comment: found more settings here:
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/AllApps/menuId/
and there I can delete it (and much more)

why I can mention you by @... ?

Comment: That's a great link! I hope that it helps someone else :) and not sure why the @ doesn't work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯