# Users outside of own tenant cannot call getAccessTokenAsync in Outlook add-in (Error: 13005 Missing grant for this add-in)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

Our Outlook add-in works well for users *in the same tenant* as the add-in.

However, `Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync()` returns a 13005 error ("Missing grant for this add-in") for Office365 users outside of our tenant.

I have followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2 and have set 'Supported account types' to *Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)*.

What other configuration settings would allow our own users to call `getAccessTokenAsync()` but not users from other tenants?

(Not sure if this is relevant, but our users add the add-in as a custom add-in from URL)

Comment: so you enabled the Multitenant setting and still users from other tenants can't use the add in or what?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. In the app's manifest, 'signInAudience' is set to AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount. The user can load the add-in, but getAccessTokenAsync() returns the 13005 error.

Comment: Perhaps a consent problem - as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676796/outlook-web-add-in-execution-of-getaccesstoken-returns-status-code-302

Comment: SOLVED: the underlying problem was completely different. Our tenant's users had previously granted access to the application. Access was revoked through https://myapps.microsoft.com/ and through the admin console, but somehow Outlook would still provide Access Tokens. It seems some other users have had this issue too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179197/how-can-i-revoke-the-access-granted-to-web-application-to-my-organizations-azur)